# How to create a point grid within a polygon layer?

Tags: arcgis-10.0

Want to generate a point layer, that contains the maximum points in a polygon layer. all points should have the distance of 6 meters between each other. how can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Fish net tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000002q000000) with 3 x 3 as cell size and set labels parameter to `LABELS`, or use the [Feature to point tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003m000000) with Centroid parameter.
then Clip points based on polygon boundary

Comment: Feature To Point would push you to an ArcInfo/Advanced level license - to avoid that when you use Create Fishnet make sure you choose POLYLINE and to have Labels created.

Comment: @riesentoast I'm assuming that a Clip of fishnet points created in this way using your polygon layer will meet your requirements.

Comment: for polyline option, i think that we should add intersection between those lines.

Comment: I think asker is only interested in the point feature class (labels) and will be throwing away the polylines.

Comment: is it possible to do this fishnet tool for each element of the polygon layer separate? because the layer has elements with different forms and i dont believe i will get so the maximum points for each element.

Comment: and yes i'm only interested in the points feature class (labels) ;)

Comment: you got to make the fishnet for the polygons extent then make a clip to extract the points inside the polygon

Comment: I think it would be beneficial to update the post to 1) Include Labels (points) and 2) Clip points based on polygon boundary.

Comment: hmm i dont get the fishnet for the polygons extent. it should be like here: http://s7.directupload.net/file/d/3207/bi9lrqov_jpg.htm

Comment: when i do it for one element as example, it looks like this http://s1.directupload.net/images/130327/74wg7zjl.jpg

Comment: try to set the labels parameter to `LABELS`